# Aggregation and filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, group-summaries

I have this table:

```
**ID    val1     val2**
1      5         6
2      6         4
3      3         1
4      8         4
5      2         6
6      8         2
```

Using filter query in Django, I want to summarize these data so that I get the mean values of val1 and val2 on each n records.  For example if n=3 then:

```
**ID     val1     val2**
1      4.7      3.7
2      6.0      4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your models first, then you can use `Count, Min, Sum, Avg` from `django.db.models` that will let you do:

```
Table.objects.aggregate(average_val1=Avg('table__val1'))
```

The result dictionary will have a key called 'average_val1'. If no such alias were specified, it would be the rather long 'table__val1__avg'.

More documentation can be found here: [Django documentation - Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

NB: You can filter then use the aggregation to execute the operations on a specific set.
Egg:

```
Table.objects.filter( pk__in=id_list ).aggregate(average_val1=Avg('table__val1'))
```

or you can determine each time the limit ids [id1, id2] for each n then do this:

```
Table.objects.filter( pk__lte=n1, pk__gte=n2).aggregate(average_val1=Avg('table__val1'))
```

The `__in, __lte, __gte` will make sure to filter only the id set you want, then you can aggregate on that set.

`__in`: in a list, `__lte`: Less than or equal and `__gte`: Greater than or equal.

Comment: I want aggregation according to each n records. I have not a field for grouping.

Comment: You can filter then aggregate ;) !

Comment: Thank you. But suppose I have a table with 20000 records and n = 4. Then I have to run "Table.objects.filter" 5000 times and each time id_list must change with new IDs.!

Comment: I see what you mean, I can't think of a way to do this in one line in Django, you can use the `Table.objects.all().extra()` API to run SQL directly ! or you can just use the `Less/Greater than or equal` to avoid listing the ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
ind = 0
v1ofn = 0
v2ofn = 0
for row in tname.objects.all():
    if ind >= n:
        result_list.append([v1ofn/3, v2ofn/3])
        v1ofn = row.val1
        v2ofn = row.val2
        ind = 0
    else:
        v1ofn = v1ofn + row.val1
        v2ofn = v2ofn + row.val2
    ind = ind + 1
```

assuming the table has multiple of 3 items, if not, do some extra logic after loop to handle the extras.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Aggregation is the Django way to do this, but suggested example would produce shitload of queries as Behesti said. And my guess is that that django ORM is really not built for number crunching (but i might be wrong here!)

I would maybe go with numpy (if you are really having huge array, i guess you need to do some partitioning):

The good sides using numpy is that its usually quite much faster than 'standard' python operations, but bad side is that its extra dependency.

```
import numpy
raw_array = [ # This is for testing the code, use .values_list( 'val1', 'val2' ) with db
[1   ,   5      ,   6],
[2   ,   6      ,   4],
[3   ,   3      ,   1],
[4   ,   8      ,   4],
[5   ,   2      ,   6],
[6   ,   8      ,   2],
[7   ,   1      ,   1],
]

arr = numpy.array( raw_array )

def sum_up_every_n_items( arr, n ):
   res = numpy.zeros( (numpy.floor( arr.shape[0]/float(n) ), arr.shape[1]) )
   arr = arr[ 0:res.shape[0]*n, : ] # Truncate, take only full N items
   for loop in range(0,n): # Note: this is loop 0,1,2 if n=3 ! We do addition with numpy vectors!
      res = res + arr[ loop::n, : ] # Get every n'th row from starting with offset
   res = res / float(n)
   return res 

res = sum_up_every_n_items( arr, n=3 )
print res
```

outputs

```
[[ 2.          4.66666667  3.66666667]
 [ 5.          6.          4.        ]]
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, because if you really have huge tables you will be consuming a lot of RAM !!

Comment: You get best performance by consuming ram. As i wrote, if you have HUGE datasets you need to partition the calculation (do the .values_list from filtered queryset).

Comment: in a HUGE datasets best is to optimize your algorithm and do batch processing, sure it will take a bit more time but at list you won't run out of RAM.

Comment: I am not quite following you. Just put single for loop on top of that .values_list with say 2**30 elements and you surely wont run out of ram AND its optimized in the sense that it will use native code for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing many queries. Pull the data down one time and do the rest in Python;

```
n = 3 #yourstep
results = Model.objects.filter(query).only('id', 'val1', 'val2')
avgs = {}
for i in xrange(0, len(results), n): # unsure, but count may end up in 2 queries, and you're going to evaluate the queryset anyway
    avg1, avg2 = 0, 0
    for j in xrange(n):
        avg1 += results[i+j].val1/float(n)
        avg2 += results[i+j].val2/float(n)
    avgs[results[i].id] = (avg1, avg2) # Why is id relevant at all here?
```

Comment: Thank you Martol1ni. I think your solution is logical.I will test it.